# What's the significance of apples in the OP?

Tags: denkigai-no-honya-san

In the OP for the Denki-gai anime, it seems that apples are the main theme.
Not only is the song called *"Kajirikake no Ringo" (A Half-Bitten Apple)*, but apples are also seen several times:

[image: "Shooting apple"?] [image: An "apple mango"?]
[image: Instant apple noodles?] [image: Everyone has an apple!]

I don't remember anything apple-related in the manga, so I'm assuming this is no reference to something that has happened there.
**What's the significance of the apples?**

Comment: The characters look pretty surprised, enough to say that maybe this was the expected effect on the viewers as well.

Comment: Apples are the new tanuki.

Comment: Not knowing the series, i can tell a bit about the significance of apples in general and you decide if it relates or not, so they are generally connected to temptation (adam and eve) and knowledge, forbidden knowledge. In snow white the witch (evil side of the woman) offers the apple tentativelty to Snow White (good side of the woman) and as she bites she dies, or takes the semblance of death, until the male rescues her, from herself, her evil self. In the biblical story the biting the apple also results in suffering, and punishment, again related to forbidden knowledge, or loss of innocence.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that would apply to this series in particular. Or if it does, I can't see how. Also, on a totally unrelated and off-topic note, it is my understanding that, although generally depicted as an apple, [the forbidden fruit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_fruit#Identifying_the_fruit) was never explicitly stated to be one.

Comment: Well it is red. The color of desire and passion. Also you have eaten some apples...it's a pretty nice thing, pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

The lyrics of the song give some clue as to what this could mean. Here are the original lyrics in Japanese. I've cut out all the verses except the choral ones which mention apples. The others are slightly relevant but not necessary.

> あまくて切ない　わたしのココロ
>   齧って逃げた子　だーれだ
>   ゆらゆら揺れてる　わたしのココロ
>   恋する気持ちは　齧りかけの林檎
>
> 傷つきたくない　わたしのココロ
>   齧って逃げた子　だーれだ
>   ふるふる震える　わたしのココロ
>   恋する気持ちは　齧りかけの林檎
>
> 夢を見ていても　空を見てても
>   想ってしまうの…君を
>   キラキラ　ハジける　2人の季節
>   待ってる気持ちは　齧りかけの林檎
>
> ゆらゆら揺れてる　わたしのココロ
>   恋する気持ちは　齧りかけの林檎

Here's an English translation of the above. I've prioritized literal accuracy in the translation, so it isn't particularly poetic and the lines are rearranged a bit to make them flow in English.

> Who was it that took and then fled
>   a bite from my sweet, painful heart.
>   The feeling of love in my wavering heart
>   is like a half-eaten apple.
>
> Who was it that took and then fled
>   a bite from my fragile heart.
>   The feeling of love in my trembling heart
>   is like a half-eaten apple.
>
> Whether I'm dreaming, or looking up in the clouds,
>   I can't help but think... of you.
>   The sparkling, popping feeling of waiting for our season together
>   is like a half-eaten apple.
>
> The feeling of love in my wobbling heart
>   is like a half-eaten apple.

From this, it's clear that, in the context of the lyrics of the song, the apple is a metaphor for the singer's heart. It is half-bitten because a piece of it was bit off by someone. Exactly who among the characters the singer is supposed to represent is unclear. The singer is Taketatsu Ayana, who is also the seiyuu of Fu-girl, but it seems like the lyrics could apply equally well to most of the female characters in the series, and indeed based on the animation it seems to be for all of them.

If we take this to apply to the scenes in the OP animation, the fact that the characters find apples seems to symbolize them discovering their love. The OP also features the pairings between Umio and Sensei, Hio and Kantoku, and Fu-girl and Sommelier, which seems to more-or-less reaffirm this interpretation. The apples they have in the OP aren't half-eaten, but I'm not sure there's any reason to read into that very far.

As for why they chose an apple as the object of the metaphor, I don't know. There could be a reference that I'm missing. This is perhaps a large part of the question, so I'm not convinced this answer is complete.